# Getting image name of iphone photo library

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I'm doing a project to take images from iphone photo library or in other way from camera roll. I have done that without any problem. But i need to retrieve the name from the photo library. Is there a way to do that? Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at ALAssetsLibrary which is available in iOS 4.0 and later.

Also, these links may help

[How to get a photo's original filename in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180880/how-to-get-a-photos-original-filename-in-ios)

[iPhone: How do I get the file path of an image saved with UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457904/iphone-how-do-i-get-the-file-path-of-an-image-saved-with-uiimagewritetosavedpho)

Answer (score 1):

If you need the full path, just use this:

```
ALAsset* asset;   // previously assigned
NSDictionary* pathInfo = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs];
```

This will leave the full URL of the image on your device as the Value member of the pathInfo object.