# Copy image from assets-library to an app folder

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, nsurl, alassetslibrary

I have an UIImagePickerController and I would like to save a selected image to my app. I can do that easy by getting the current UIImage and save it (by creating a file) but I would prefer to directly copy the file from Library to my folder.
So now I have an URL of the selected image : UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL which return a specific  pattern "assets-library". I tried to copy an image from this kind of URL to a path but without success.

Is there a way to success on what I would like to do ?
Thanks !

Comment: Does this help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180880/how-to-get-a-photos-original-filename-in-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through two ways

**First Way:** Using **imagePickerController** *`didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`* delegate

```
-  (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

     UIImage *selectedImage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    //save selectedImage to document directory      

 }
```

**Second Way:** Using `ALAssetLibrary`.

For this you have to save the `ALAsset URL` and retrieve the image using `ALAssetLibrary`, please refer [my answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508535/add-uiimageview-into-uiscrollview-inside-block-with-alasset/13508841#13508841) .Just put your `ALAsset url` instead of `asseturl`