# Getting the actual image name from the assets

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I am developing a phoneGap application in IOS where I use `getPhoto('Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY');` 
to access the photo library and select an image. following is the onPhotoURISuccess method where I need to get the url of the image and pass it to my native plugin to validate it's filesize, resolution and file extension.

this is my getPhoto() method

```
// A button will call this function
    function getPhoto(source)
    {            
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 100,
                                    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI, sourceType: source });
    }
```

and this is the onPhotoURISuccess method,

```
// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI)
    {
        img_uri = imageURI;
        console.log('NATIVE_URI==>'+img_uri);

        // Get image handle
        var imgPrev = document.getElementById('imgPreview');

        // Unhide image elements
        imgPrev.style.display = 'block';

        // Show the captured photo
        // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
        imgPrev.src = imageURI;

    }
```

I have three options for this according to the phoneGap documentation. using DATA_URL, FILE_URI or NATIVE_URI.
FILE_URI seems to be hiding underlying data of the image where it always returns me a jpeg image thus the actual extension is hidden

assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=5CF16D20-9A80-483A-AC1C-9692123610B1&ext=JPG
I want to know how to get the actual image name along with the extension from this.

I need to get the image name and validate the extension.

someone please do help me with posssible approach for me to follow

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180880/how-to-get-a-photos-original-filename-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

If you could get an url to asset, which is

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=5CF16D20-9A80-483A-AC1C-9692123610B1&ext=JPG
```

You can get real name of file, by this asset:

```
NSString* originalFileName = [[yourALAsset defaultRepresentation] filename];
```