# Accessing filename out of nsurl and converting the same to base 64

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the following code to retrieve an image.

```
UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

NSURL *path = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
NSString *base64String = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

1. When I try to print the path, its printing the entire file path but How can I get the file name out of `NSURL`?
2. After accessing the path, I wish to convert the image to `base 64` using the path. How can I do so?

Comment: Why are you using `valueForKey:`?  What does "I wish to convert the image to base 64 using the path" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the file name using

```
NSString *theFileName = [[string lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

And use below code for base64 conversation

```
- (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*) theData
{
    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: it prints `asset` as the filename for all images

Answer (score 0):

You can get name like,

```
 NSURL *imagePath = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

 NSString *imageName = [imagePath lastPathComponent];
```

Comment: it is printing `asset.JPG` for all images bro

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're passing the wrong key

```
NSURL *url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSString *fileName = url.lastPathComponent;
```

Comment: it prints `asset` as the filename for all images

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180880/how-to-get-a-photos-original-filename-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope it would be helpful!!
import AssetsLibrary in your file:

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
```

And, in

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

put

```
    // get the ref url
NSURL *refURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

// define the block to call when we get the asset based on the url (below)
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
    NSLog(@"[imageRep filename] : %@", [imageRep filename]);
};

// get the asset library and fetch the asset based on the ref url (pass in block above)
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:refURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];
```

And another Way you can do like that!!!

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as NSURL
let imageName = imageURL.path!.lastPathComponent
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as String
let localPath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)

let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
data.writeToFile(localPath, atomically: true)

let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: localPath)!
let photoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath)
let imageWithData = UIImage(data: imageData)!

picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

}

Comment: ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock is deprecated