# Is there really no way to retrieve the original filename of a photo from the photo library ?

Tags: ios

I found some interesting topics, such as : 
- [How to get a photo's original filename in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180880/how-to-get-a-photos-original-filename-in-ios)
or : 
- [Retrieving a filename for an ALAsset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048640/retrieving-a-filename-for-an-alasset)

but it says that you can read the local filename of the picture, but not the original name from the source image. 
Indeed, on ios, the pictures are renamed to :

/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/XXXAPPLE/IMG_XXXX.JPG ou .PNG

but when I sync my phone, itunes knows which pictures are already synced, so there must be a link between the original filename and the new ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure speculation: it's possible that iTunes could know both the original filename and the "synched" filename that is used on the iOS device, while iOS knows only the local name, which would make it impossible to retrieve the original filename on the iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

iOS tries to be different than many OSes in that it does not push the abstraction of content into filesystem (files, filenames, folders and so on). In some situations it might be better to continue on this path.