# ALAsset "real" filename

Tags: ios, xcode, alassetslibrary, alasset

I have transfered an MP4 from iTunes to my iPad.  If I open the Videos app I can see it listed  - there's the thumbnail and the filename below (my_file.mp4).  However the actual filename of the asset is changed in iOS to some unique value - IMG_001.MOV, for example.  I would like to get the the original filename as it is listed in the Videos app (my_file.mp4).  How are where do I find this?

Thanks

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8528896/902424 answer

Hope it helps

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't give me the original filename - rather the filename which iOS/iTunes created when the file was moved over.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a Code to get the Real name of AssetsFile**

```
ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock assetsEnumerationBlock = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

        if (result) {
            [self.arrAssetsMedia addObject:result];
        }

        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [result defaultRepresentation];

        if (rep.filename!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"File name is::%@",rep.filename);
            [arrMediaFileName addObject:rep.filename];
        }
    };
```

Note:ALAssetRepresentation has a property **- (NSString *)filename** with the help of this we can get the file name

Answer (score 0):

You Can't get the MP4 file from your device with its original name.

The only way to retrieve the PhotoGallery item (photos/videos) from your device to your application is through **ALAssetLibrary**.

The items will have names such as **assets-library://asset/asset.MP4?id=1000000001&ext=MP4**

So you can track the URL and get the MP4 using **ALAsset Library**.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case.  Would be interested to know how the Video app manages to get the filename, however.  I've had to re-write my application to use iCloud instead.