# Get MIME type of an ALAsset

Tags: ios, mime-types, alasset

Is there a way how to get MIME type for ALAsset? There is a nice method for metadata:

```
NSDictionary *data = [[asset defaultRepresentation] metadata];
```

But that doesn't contain MIME type data...

Comment: As far as the documentation goes, the best we can do is get the asset type (photo/video/unknow).

Comment: Right but what if Apple suddenly changes the way they store the images? Like...sure it is image/jpeg, because I know it's that way. But what if it changes? Isn't there more universal way? :(

Comment: Wait, I think I found it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048640/retrieving-a-filename-for-an-alasset - I NSLogged the filename with last answer here (`ALAssetRepresentation`), and it say JPG/PNG for the images I selected.

Comment: I know this does not give you a generic response, but this is the best I could salvage from the web. Sorry.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

NSString* MIMEType = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass
             ((__bridge CFStringRef)[rep UTI], kUTTagClassMIMEType);
```

This will give you the MIME type. You need to add MobileCoreService framework and import `<MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`