# Photos framework checking image type

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, swift

I have code for fetching the photos from the library and accessing the types. But i have no idea how to check whether the image is PNG or JPEG.? by ALAssetLibrary we can do this easily. I want to implement this by Photos framework. Anyone have any idea.? Any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
let asset: PHAsset = ...
let opts = PHImageRequestOptions()
// opts.synchronous = true // If you want synchronous callback
opts.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersion.Original
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(asset, options: opts) { _, uti, _, _ in
    println(uti)
}
```

I don't know how to do this **without** fetching actual data.

---

To convert UTI to MIME-Type:

```
import MobileCoreServices

let uti = ...
let mime = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti, kUTTagClassMIMEType).takeRetainedValue()
```

Comment: uti is returning nil. do u know why? @rintaro

Comment: for <PHAsset: 0x154fcc630> D5D99B86-A3B7-4D30-B93B-8CDC8B7CA354/L0/001 mediaType=2/0, sourceType=1, (1080x1920), creationDate=2016-08-30 06:01:00 +0000, location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this stack answer using which you can get type of you asset.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22352132/2098690

Comment: didn't you check my question, i don't want to do that ALAsset. I want to do it with PHAsset