# get MIME type from Assets Library URL iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mime-types, alassetslibrary

I am trying to upload image, but in the post request  I need to pass "Content-Type" i.e the mime type of the image which I have picked from iOS Photo library, but when **I am trying to get the mime type it is coming nil**.

*Here is the process :-*

**Note:**  imgProfileURL is of type `NSString`

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        imgProfileURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]];

    }
```

**imgProfileURL now contains:-**

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=B6C0A21C-07C3-493D-8B44-3BA4C9981C25&ext=JPG
```

Now, I am calling the below function to get MIME type and passing the value of imgProfileURL

```
- (NSString *)mimeTypeForPath:(NSString *)path
{
    // get a mime type for an extension using MobileCoreServices.framework



    CFStringRef extension = (__bridge CFStringRef)[path pathExtension];
    CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, extension, NULL);
    assert(UTI != NULL);

    NSString *mimetype = CFBridgingRelease(UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType));  //it is NULL
    assert(mimetype != NULL); // Crashing here

    CFRelease(UTI);

    return mimetype;
}
```

**`mimetype` is coming NULL here.**

I have gone through this question , but didn't help me:- [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351587/get-mime-type-of-an-alasset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is What I did to get image name, type and size:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *imgSelected = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        NSString *fileName = [representation filename];
        NSString *fileSize = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",[representation size]];
        NSString *MIMEType = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass
        ((__bridge CFStringRef)[representation UTI], kUTTagClassMIMEType);

        NSLog(@"file name : %@",fileName);
        NSLog(@"file size : %@",fileSize);
        NSLog(@"file type : %@",MIMEType);
    };

    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] ;
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:fileURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hi. can you give the equivalent using photos framework