# Get original video name as selected from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I get the name of video file selected from Camera roll or any other album in `UIImagePickerController`'s delegate method ?

I'm able to get the name of image but if using same in video it's returning `nil`.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: you will getting URL. from that you can easily fetch the name i think. URL for image and video will be different.

Comment: @Wolverine: I'm getting this url for selected video

assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=1489CFE5-A447-456E-A641-DC44818C1D44&ext=MOV
Now how will I retrieve the name here.

Comment: In this case.. this might will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048640/retrieving-a-filename-for-an-alasset

Answer (score 2):

```
     - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

            if (![mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
                return;

            mediaURl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

            //NSLog(@"mediaURL %@",mediaURl);
            moviePath = mediaURl.absoluteString;
            //  NSLog(@"moviePath %@",moviePath);
            tempFilePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
            NSLog(@"filepath %@",tempFilePath);
            //if you want only file name
            NSArray *ar = [tempFilePath componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
            NSString *filename = [[ar lastObject] uppercaseString];
            NSLog(@"filename %@",filename);
    }
```

Let me know if you have any issues

Comment: I'm getting name of video file as "69DF7DDF-1D8B-414B-8F2D-2E6BB1E537EB.MOV"... Is this the way the name will come?

Comment: Yes. @RohitaxRajguru

Comment: Its default name but if you want you can replace it according to your requirement.@RohitaxRajguru

Comment: i think you are able to get the name of the video file, so your question is answered. Can you accept the answer so that it may be helpful for others. @RohitaxRajguru

Comment: Thanks for the efforts.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is super old but i thought if someone finds it, here is a working answer in swift:

```
func fileName(for infoDict: [String : Any]) -> String? {
    guard let referenceURL = infoDict[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL else { return nil }
    let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [referenceURL], options: nil)
    guard let asset = result.firstObject else { return nil }
    let firstResource = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset).first
    return firstResource?.originalFilename ?? asset.value(forKey: "filename") as? String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 or later
Working on My Side for the captured image

Use :

```
    imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]){
            let fileName = FileInfo.getMediaName(info: info)
      }
```

class : pleas put the method **info[:]**

```
class FileInfo {
    // Return Media name
    static func getMediaName(info:[String : Any]) -> String {

        if let asset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset {
            let assetResources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset)
            let firstObj = assetResources.first?.originalFilename as! NSString
            print(firstObj)
            return firstObj
        }
    }
}
```

// IMG_02256.jpeg

Comment: What should XXX_00256.jpeg be? Please [edit] your answer.

Comment: If you want to show us the picture, then you need to provide a link, not only the name.